# How to get Public IP via AWS CLI while launching

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My AWS Command is:

```
> aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-346b2354 --count 1 --instance-type c4.large --key-name my-cali-key --security-group-ids sg-a168c7c4
```

When I trigger this, the JSON data that it returns has only the Private IP address and NOT the Public IP address.

```
 ................ DATA  OMITTED................... 

                "Groups": [
                    {
                        "GroupName": "launch-wizard-1", 
                        "GroupId": "sg-a168c7c4"
                    }
                ], 
                "SubnetId": "subnet-cb2524ae", 
                "OwnerId": "012710546082", 
                "PrivateIpAddress": "172.31.17.252"
            }

 ..................... DATA OMITTED ....................
```

[(Image) Browser look of the same instance with Public IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8p50z.png)

However when I see in the browser I immediately notice a Public IP address being associated automatically. **How Can I fetch the public IP of launched instances?** Kindly do not get confused with elastic-IP and its association with instances. I know to associate an elastic-IP but the need here is different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances \
  --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].PublicIpAddress" \
  --output=text
```

Another Way is

```
curl --silent http://ipecho.net/plain
```

This will return Public IP of instance

Comment: Any trick to convert text data into json? --output=json gives me in a way that is not really json